# Dynamics 365 OAuth doesn't return refresh token

Tags: office365, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I need to get a long lived refresh token via OAuth when authorizing a user to their Dynamics 365 environment. But when I make my request no refresh_token value is returned.

Here is the URL format I'm using for the OAuth request.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource={Uri.EscapeDataString(options.field1)}&client_id={clientid}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUrl)}
```

It calls my callback URL properly and I then exchange the "code" for the access token using a grant_type of "authorization_code". Notice there isn't a refresh_token.

[image]

I've configured the Azure permissions like so for the "app registration":

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out actually. The URL needs to be formatted as a version 2 URL and there isn't a "resource" parameter in version 2 but instead you pass the resource in the "scopes" parameter.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientid}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUrl)}&scope={Uri.EscapeDataString("offline_access https://xxx.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation")}
```